# How can I copy the Action value in an Html form

Tags: c#, html, httprequest

I wanna be able to get the "The Merinda Flat Sandal In Silver" this is in  a form this is the code `<p class="product_note">The Merinda Flat Sandal In Silver</p>`
I wanna copy it to a string like in the code below but to get the text and not the value

````
string id = "https://www.factory54.co.il/products/Logo-canvas-sneakers-in-White-No-167";
            Console.WriteLine(HtmlAgi(id)); 

        }
        public static string HtmlAgi(string url)
        {

            var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = Webget.Load(url);
            HtmlNode ourNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(("//form[@class]"));

            if (ourNode != null)
            {


                return ourNode.GetAttributeValue("class", "");

            }
            else
            {
                return "not fount";
            }

        }```
```<div class="produtshow clearfix">
                                                                                            <h1 id="manufacturer_header"><a href="https://www.factory54.co.il/designers/stuart-weitzman" title="Stuart Weitzman">Stuart Weitzman</a>                                    <p class="product_note">The Merinda Flat Sandal In Silver</p>
                                </h1>

</div>```
And here is where the text is in the html file (this is located in a form)
````

Comment: This need more explanation. Where is this HTML coming from. What kind of C# program are you running?

Comment: This is just an example for an html form. I'm running HttpRequest but before I do I wanna know the action thats why i need this I mean the program gets URL and copies the value of action

Comment: Still not clear. Let me put it another way: why can't you just read the HTML into your C# program and search through it for the text you want?

Comment: Sounds great to me how do i do this|?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack

Comment: Thank you but I'm trying to get as input the URL of the html site and then read it and find the action value do u know how can i do this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help if you won't explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: I am sorry here is a little more clear explanation

Comment: Check the post again please

Comment: That's a lot better, but for future reference it would be better still to have left in something of the original question. The current question makes little sense to anyone who hasn't been following its evolution.

Comment: I'd suggest you revert this to the original question, otherwise the answer will make no sense to anyone looking in future. The point is not simply to answer questions, but to build up a resource for others with similar questions in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the SelectSingleNode line to:

```
HtmlNode ourNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(("//form[@action]"));
```

To read multiple for elements, use:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string id = "https://www.factory54.co.il/products/Logo-canvas-sneakers-in-White-No-167";
    HtmlAgi(id);
}

public static void HtmlAgi(string url)
{
    var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = Webget.Load(url);
    var ourNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(("//form[@action]"));

    foreach (var node in ourNodes)
        Console.WriteLine(node.GetAttributeValue("action", ""));
}
```

It's down to you to determine which one your want.

Comment: First of all thanks for helping out, I got an output but not the output I wanted maybe it's because there's more then one form/action in this html anyway to solve this?

Comment: I got another question I updated the post if u can help I'll appreciate

Comment: Post it as a new question and I'll be happy to give it a go. Makes life easier for everyone.